# Symfony 2.6 : Error in prod : ClassNotFoundException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2616

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 2.6.4 for my project. Everything working fine on local but when i try on my prod server I got this error :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
> ClassNotFoundException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2616:
> Attempted to load class "EnvParametersResource" from namespace > "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config".
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
> in bootstrap.php.cache line 2616

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: did you clear your cache? ``app/console cache:clear --env=prod``

Comment: yes i did already, and still not working

Comment: Did you only configured your route on the dev config but not on the production config? Was everything deleted after the cache clear?

Comment: The route are config on routing.yml and routing_dev.yml, routing_dev only include routes for WebProfiler. There is no file in cache folder. I deleted them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, i discover that the file Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\EnvParametersResource was not corretly been uploaded. I uploaded again and now everything working fine